# The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found -- error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am trying to use DevExpress with vs2010 , and got that error .

It comes from line  `private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList treeList1;`

But I have already a Reference to that `DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v9.3` and have there copy

local flag set to true.

How i can solve that issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v9.3 depends on other assemblies to run. Make sure you also have the following references:

```
DevExpress.Data.v9.3
DevExpress.Utils.v9.3
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v9.3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the 3 of them but still i have the same problem

Comment: Are you targeting for .Net 4.0?

Comment: Try changing it to 3.5 - I don't think they are ready for 4.0 so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the class doesn't exist in that version of the assembly. Have you tried using Object Browser to navigate the namespace tree?

Comment: I think they not support 2010